# pysaml how to share extra data between saml request and saml response

Tags: python, saml, saml-2.0

I want to transmit additional information from a SAML request to a SAML response.

Is it possible to utilize the SAML configuration in the pysaml library for this task?

To elaborate, if I include a custom UUID in the SAML request, I want that information to be present in the SAML response as well.

I'm utilizing the pysaml library for this purpose. How can I achieve this?
below is my saml configuration

```
{
  'debug': True, 
  'xmlsec_binary': '/usr/bin/xmlsec1', 
  'entityid': 'XXX', 
  'service': {
    'sp': {
      'name': 'XXX SAML2 SP',
      'endpoints': {
        'assertion_consumer_service': [
          ('https://example.com/', 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST')],
        'single_sign_on_service': [
          ('http://example.com/ls/post', 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect'), 
          ('http://example.com/ls/redirect', 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect')]
      }, 
      'name_id_format': ['urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress'],
      'authn_requests_signed': True,
      'want_assertions_signed': True,
      'want_response_signed': False,
      'allow_unsolicited': True
    }
  },
  'key_file': 'private.key',
  'cert_file': 'public.cert',
  'encryption_keypairs': [
    {
      'key_file': 'private.key',
      'cert_file': 'public.cert'
    }],
    'valid_for': 8760,
    'allow_unknown_attributes': True,
    'metadata': {
      'remote': [
        'url': 'https://abc/samlp/metadata', 'disable_ssl_certificate_validation': True
      }
    ]
  }
}
```